# GKE containers and 3rd part mongoDB service

Tags: ip, mongodb, kubernetes

We want to use Google Container Engine and mLab (mongoDB cluster) service together. Containers have always public IP from node on which they are started, during scaling nodes are added/deleted so IPs are changeing all the time.

Issue is such we don't want to open our DB service to "world" and we want to white-list only IPs which can connect to our database.

Is there possibility to force GKE service to have static public IP from which it always will be connecting to our mongoDB cluster (to not use IP from node)?

I have been trying to set up externalIP for service but it is only for incomming connections, outgoing are always like described before, with public IP of node where are containers started.